# C++: Simulating key press and maintain it if pressed on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard

I have this *C++* Function that receives Virtual Key and Press/Release the key:

```
void SendKey (WORD wVk, bool press) {
   keybd_event(wVk, 0, press? 0 : KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

But it does just press the key 1 time, not constantly as I expected.

I am constructing a JoyPad simulation, so, I need to configure KeyDown and KeyUp respectively, this is a little *C++* process that reads by *cmd* the key and the type (Down, Press or Release):

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void SendKey (WORD wVk, bool press) {
    keybd_event(wVk, 0, press? 0 : KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

void PressKey (WORD wVk) {
    SendKey(wVk, true);
    Sleep(30);
    SendKey(wVk, false);
}

int main() {
    int key;
    char type;

    while(true) {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> type;

        if(key == 0) break;
        if(type == 'd') SendKey((WORD) key, true);
        if(type == 'r') SendKey((WORD) key, false);
        if(type == 'p') PressKey((WORD) key);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot, if anyone has built something similar, please tell me.

Comment: You just read the key once, then check if the key is d,r, or p.. what do you expect ?

Comment: Hi, this is a child process, so i will be simulating keys via standar output by a NodeJS process, thats why i have a infinite loop, i dont want the process to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to send a key event for each key repeat you want, this is not going to happen auto-magically. Just like the real keyboard driver sends repeated key events after the initial delay.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i gonna do it like it, i gonna search about "natural" delays of the keyboard, thanks a lot